# Detect linux version 5 or 6

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell script as I do to detect the version of linux?
with shell script would detect if the version is 5 or 6 Linux with IF if possible
to execute a block of installation.

Comment: What do you mean "Linux version 5 or 6"?  That sounds like you want to find the distribution version, not the kernel version, and doing that is distribution specific.  Anyway, hint: `uname` and `cut`

Comment: Current kernels are v3.xx, Centos distribution is v6.xx and Fedora is now v20. Linux v5 doesn't make any sense.  Which number are you looking for?

Comment: A similar question has been answered on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/89654/what-version-of-rhel-am-i-using

Comment: Please update your question to specify what version number you're really looking for. "Linux" is the name of the kernel, and its latest stable version is 3.13. You're probably looking for the version of your *distribution*; if so, please specify which distribution you're using (Red Hat, Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lsb_release -r | cut -f2` to get your distribution release version? (and `cut` again with a different delimiter to extract the major number of the release)

For instance:

```
version=`lsb_release -r | cut -f2 | cut -d. -f1`

if [ ${version} = 5 ]; then
    echo "This is version 5"
elif [ ${version} = 6 ]; then
    echo "This is version 6"
fi
```

Comment: Yes I know the command I need to know how to do shell script to detect
example
if [$ version = 5)

command if 5;

else {}

command if version 6
}

Comment: Problem solved Thank you very much, I can not use the "cut" property have to study on this expression ..
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Linux distributions and the updates people apply as well as the software they install or configure to use in place of distribution defaults vary so greatly that testing for a Linux version number is far too brittle a dependency on which to rely for an installation script. Instead, test directly for the features on which you depend and be prepared to report or install what is missing. Also, give serious thought to statically linking many of the libraries on which your code depends if you are installing compiled executables. Not every "bug fix" or "enhancement" will be compatible with your code and none of them will have been tested with it.